# How to pass query parameter in URL for twilio gather

Tags: c#, twilio-api

I'm constructing a gather in C# from Twilio and for the URL attribute of gather constructor I need to pass a query parameter. For example `"somepath?name=someName"`. However, i'm getting an exception saying that my `urlString` parameter is `null`. I tried to encode the `"somepath?name=someName"`, but didn't work.

How can I pass query parameters for Twilio gather's URI?

Answer (score 0):

I just urlencoded context data and added it to the path such as "somepath/somedata".  The only time I really need to do that was a new call where I didn't already have a CallSid to reference in the backend.

Comment: For some cases I need to pass a parameter in the uri like: "something?name=some name". I do the following:
`var gather= new Gather(
                            new[] { Gather.InputEnum.Speech }.ToList(), Url.ActionUri("something?name=some name", MyControllerName), speechTimeout: "auto");`
but it throws an exception that the uri is null. I also tried to urlencode the string before passing it as parameter, but again the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. The following solution works:
`var gather = new Gather(
                            new[] { Gather.InputEnum.Speech }.ToList(), new Uri($"{Url.ActionUri(nameof(MethodName), MyControllerName)}?name=some_name", UriKind.Relative), speechTimeout: "auto");`